# Simulate a PING operation in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to simulate a ping operation to find out if a remote host is reachable. I could not find any conclusive code samples to do this for WP7 so I figured I'd try out the following.
What I'm looking for is confirmation of whether this is the appropriate way to do this.

```
Socket socket =
                new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint (someIP, 80); // use HTTP port 80 
        args.Completed += (obj, eva) =>
        {
            if (eva.SocketError != SocketError.Success) 
            {
              //raise an error or set a view model property indicating error                    
            }                
            socket.Close();
        };
        socket.ConnectAsync(args);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless things have changed in Mango, you can only really reach other hosts with HTTP or HTTPS anyway - so "reachable" really means "is listening for web requests on a known URL"... so the simplest approach would be to make some harmless web request to the relevant server. `WebClient` is probably the simplest way of doing that, although in my experience it does more work on the UI thread than you'd really expect, so I've ended up using the lower-level `HttpWebRequest`. For a single ping-like request, you may be okay to use `WebClient`.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement Ping, but sockets are now supported in Mango.

Comment: @Jon: I updated the code to specifically connect to port 80, and the SocketError property gets set to "Success". Do you suppose using sockets to make this check would be more efficient than using WebClient or HttpWebRequest?